# Depth data from ARKit

Tags: avcapturesession, ios11, arkit

Is it possible to access the AVDepthData from ARKit?  The ARFrame contains the camera's image, but not its depth information.

I tried to create a separate AVCaptureSession to receive the AVDepthData, but I am unable to run the AVCaptureSession at the same time as ARKit.  Either the ARSCNView updates or the AVCaptureDepthDataOutputDelegate gets called, but never both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was answered in [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84927) thread and mentioned in this [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/601/), no, ARKit does not provide you with `AVDepthData` when you are in world tracking mode. The only time when you are provided with `AVDepthData` is when you are in face tracking mode using an iPhone X.

Comment: Yes, about a month after I posted this question on Stack Overflow, Apple updated the ARKit API to include AVDepthData for Face tracking and finally responded to me in that thread. I've since filed a bug report with Apple to request AVDepthData during World Tracking Mode.  So this is currently the correct answer, but hopefully Apple will update the API again in the future.

Comment: If they don't have a way to get estimated depth from rear (main) camera then why does it even have "AR" in its name? Isn't this a basic prerequisite of Augmented Reality?

Answer (score 1):

This takes a long time (about 15 seconds), but I built a depth capture function using repeated calls to hitTest.  This is probably horrendously non-optimal, but I couldn't figure out the best way to draw an image, and this is the first way I found that I really understood well enough to implement:

```js
let height = Int(arView.frame.height)
let width = Int(arView.frame.width)


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: height), true, 0)
while y < height {
  var x = 0
  while x < width {
    let location = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    let results = arView.hitTest(location, types: [.featurePoint, .existingPlane, .estimatedVerticalPlane, .estimatedHorizontalPlane, .existingPlaneUsingGeometry, .existingPlaneUsingExtent])
    let alpha = results.isEmpty ? 1.0 : (1.0 / CGFloat(results.count))
    for result in results {
      let value = 1.0 / (result.distance + 1.0)
      switch result.type {
        case .featurePoint:
          UIColor(red: value, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        case .existingPlane:
          UIColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        case .estimatedVerticalPlane:
          UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: value, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        case .estimatedHorizontalPlane:
          UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: value, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        case .existingPlaneUsingGeometry:
          UIColor(red: value, green: value, blue: value, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        case .existingPlaneUsingExtent:
          UIColor(red: value, green: value, blue: value, alpha: alpha).setFill()
        default:
          UIColor.black.setFill()
      }
      UIRectFill(CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 1, height: 1))
    }

    x += 1
  }

  y += 1

}

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

imgView.image = image
```

You can tweak the colors if you want.  Anyway, I thought this gave me a pretty good glimpse of what ARKit thought about the world.

Answer (score 0):

arkit also use AVCaptureSession, so to nowadays it's impossible to use arscnview while AVCaptureSession is going on, because it will call delegate - (void)sessionWasInterrupted:(ARSession *)session;
Only method is use replay kit to record arkit screen.

Comment: Alright, but in this case how this project is able to access AVCaptureSession in the same moment ?
https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit

Comment: If using RealityKit you can access frames from the delegate method, which provides the lates camera frame captured.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 you can use frameSemantics

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.frameSemantics = .personSegmentationWithDepth
```

Then, in the ARSessionDelegate callback you can access the estimatedDepthData from the ARFrame

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
     let estimatedDepthData = frame.estimatedDepthData
     ....
}
```

You can also check

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/3152989-estimateddepthdata

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2984226-segmentationbuffer

Comment: When using the above mentioned, i get the following exception:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'This set of frame semantics is not supported on this configuration'`

So i guess even on iOS13, this is still not supported :\